# Why don't moderators want to close this typo-error question?

Tags: support, flags, close-reasons

In regards to [empty SUM() with dynamic value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152339/empty-sum-with-dynamic-value) , the error was a typo from OP in the sense that they were entering the wrong id (they searched for `244` when they wanted `224`). So the code that they supplied is entirely correct, there's absolutely no error in it, just the typo in the id in regards to their database.

I flagged it as a typo error, but the flag gets rejected with *"flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"*.

Shouldn't this be closed and/or deleted? I mean sure people sometimes enter wrong input variables, but that has nothing to do with the question originally asked. The way I see it, this is not a programming error and serves no historical purpose. Or does it in a way I can't see?

Comment: Considering that this seems to be a fairly common issue, you might want to overlook either the process or the UI when "moderator intervention" is selected. For example, if the input field had sniffed our text inputs and compared them to close reasons, it could have suggested those close actions to us instead.

Comment: agree; at sites where I have < 3K rep I find that UI to flag to close is... suboptimal (softly speaking). I guess they don't change it because after one finally finds a way to proper flag options, they stop making mistakes

Comment: Well, it's (hopefully) a one-time event for each user, IF they understand what went wrong. I didn't really until just now, for example. And the comment I got back didn't explain at all what I should have done instead. That's what I mean that the process could be improved, instead of just rejecting it could also have urged me to use the correct channel.

Comment: It has 5 votes and no downvotes, moderators are never exactly keen on deleting popular content.  I could post a snarky comment about php questions but that would be too easy :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should flag to close it, there are specific flag reasons for such posts.

Moderators do not need to be involved here, so your custom flag was declined.

Comment: So it was because I initially chose "moderator intervention"? I don't know if "typo error" existed at the time of the flagging, either that or I didn't find it. But I have flagged to close it now, we'll see how that goes. Thanks!

Comment: @Jan: wait, why are you asking about a flag that was declined **two years ago**?

Comment: It's still wrong and should still be closed and/or deleted. Right?

Comment: @Jan: if it is a simple typo, feel free to flag it for closure. It'll go into the closure queue and the community takes it from there.

Comment: @Jan: the specific Typo close reason was introduced in September 2014, but there were other applicable reasons before.